# Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.ads.adinfo

Tags: android, android-studio

I had a working Android project developed under Eclipse, and didn't continue development for about a year. Somewhere in between, I had a beta version of Android studio upgrade my project...and now finally, I loaded it with the current version and tried to run it in the emulator (API 15, Android 4.0.3, x86 cpu kernel).
However, the following error message came up and the app was terminated:

```
E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.ads.adinfo
E/webkit: Exception: content://com.google.android.gms.ads.adinfo/any.gif
```

Any idea what's the reason and how to fix it? The app compiled fine for the same environment when I still did it under Eclipse... It kinda feels like requirements and/or declarations may have changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    In between the world has also moved from maven to gradle build system , you need to add following into your gradle

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
        ...

        dependencies {
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'

        }
```